# How to make a GDSL file in a jar get picked up in another project in Intellij?

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

I have a project with a GDSL file that describes a DSL delegate like:

```
def ctx = context  pathRegexp: ".*installer\\.groovy", scope: scriptScope()
contributor(ctx) {
   delegatesTo(findClass("com.whatever.InstallerBase"))
}
```

I package this file up in the jar (just in the root of the jar) using maven.

In a separate project I have a maven dependency on my jar artifact containing the gdsl.  However, my autocompletion doesn't work.  It works fine with the sample scripts in the first project (with the GDSL).

Is there a step that I'm missing in order for the GDSL to be picked up?  Do I need to place it in a special folder in the jar?

Comment: One thing to try is File | Invalidate Caches and restart.

Another one — ensure that the library jar is only attached as classes and not library source as well.

Comment: Thanks @PeterGromov but why should it be a problem if its attached as source? I always import maven source + documentation.  That must be my problem as I'm not getting Gpars dsl right now but if I ctrl+shift+n for Definitions.gdsl I see two entries: one for the jar and one for the sources jar.  Is there any IDEA youtrack issue I can vote for?

Comment: Because the code is written so :(. If IDEA ran gdsl from both classes and source, it might result in running the same script twice, which could lead to performance degradation and possibly duplicate variants. But if gdsl file is in library classes jar, it should be executed now. There's no YouTrack issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed what @PeterGromov indicated in the comment on the question:

> ensure that the library jar is only attached as classes and not library source as well

both the source and library were configured and thus IDEA doesn't include it.  I have opened a youtrack issue to fix this here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137411